# What group do these types of numbers fall into?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question today is whether or not there is a specific group for triangular numbers, square numbers, pentagonal numbers, hexagonal numbers, heptagonal numbers e.tc.

If there is, please tell me! Also, I have discovered a formula which seems to work which works out the n-th term of any sequence using the number of vertices in which it has. If you are interested, please message me (I think you can?) If not, just comment below and I'll try to get in touch with you.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff - Well I'm wondering if there is a group / category that numbers like triangle numbers, pentagonal numbers e.tc. fall into. Is there a specific name for this group of numbers. Something like shaped numbers?

Comment: They are called figurate numbers.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you! Also, do you know if a formula to work out all figurate numbers has been discovered yet? Could you write this as an answer as well so that other people can find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called *polygonal* numbers, see here also for formulas http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number